# Good web reports designer

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, reporting

I faced wuth task of creating system that will generate various medical papers for patients based on DB data. There is a lot of 3d party companies that will use this product therefore this product will be web-based. The main purpose of this product is printing this papers I have described above. Users already has prepared paper blank on which personal information will be imprinted. All users has various printers and the main issue I need to solve is that every printer prints in own maner and imprinted characters losts their positions.

The possible way I can solve this is to provide reports designer embedded in system, that allow every user "adjust" report to get printer prints properly. 
By the way, we has all necessary documents reports storing in .fr3 files. It's 'cause we use same reports in another desktop application and we use fast report engine in that application. So the only one web reports designer [I have found is Stimul soft reports web designer](http://web.stimulsoft.com/Designer.aspx). But it's big, awkward and seems too heavy for this small project. Could you guys advice me some lightweight web reports designer/engine that can solve my issue?

P.S.: sorry for my English. I will use ASP .NET MVC3 (C#) for implementing this project.

Answer (score 1):

The key question is do you need report design via the browser, do you merely need printer positioning, or can the report design be performed on the user's computer and it's just report generation that must be on the browser.

If you need report design in the browser then you are limited to products like Stimulsoft which as you said tend to be ackward and limited.

What you may be facing, based on your question, is that you need to position the report on the printer as all printers set the upper left of the generated report in a slightly different place on the paper. The best way to handle this issue is to make your report work fine regardless of the upper left of the printing on the page as the differences are small. But if that won't work, just prompt the user for the adjustment values.

Finally, if you want a system where it is very easy for non programmers to design reports, and the designer can be on their computer, please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/) (disclaimer - I'm the CTO at Windward. With Windward you design your reports in Microsoft Word, Excel, or PowerPoint so it is both very easy and very powerful.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that I limited to products like stimulsoft. I need to adjust some reports in a browser. Could you recommend me another one?

Comment: kseen - I'm sorry but design in browser report designers I do not know well so I cannot recomend another. (Design on your desktop I do know well.)

Answer (score 1):

I does not understand what your problem is with position. A normal reporting solution print identical on different printers (not valid for old 9 dot printer).

Do you want print in a form (blank)? i-net Clear Reports has a page option for form print and an [Online Designer](https://www.inetsoftware.de/reporting/public/jnlp/designer.jnlp). You find the form print option in the page setup dialog. If you enable the form print option the left and right margin will not change and the print will not scale.

Or do you search a simple designer in a browser? Then you can take a look in the [ad-hoc reporting](https://www.inetsoftware.de/reporting/public/remote/adhoc).

Comment: But it says my collegues that has more experience in this way. Could you recommend me please some products what allow design report in browser scope?

Comment: Which features should have this browser designer? The ad.Hoc reporting link show a browser designer.

Comment: The more features is better. At the momentwe need that feature allows changing position of some report elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL-Server reporting services (2008 R2 in it's latest and most bug-corrected version).

It can render to HTML, and export to PDF, XLS, CSV and to Word (Word only with a commercial custom extension).
It also has a COM-object, which allows the report to run standalone, without SSRS installed.
SSRS also supports OracleProvider, apart from SQL server.

If a MS-SQL dependency is an overkill, you could take a look at Eclipse BIRT, which is a Java SSRS clone, which has a web viewer and JDBC database connectivity (however, the report format is not compatible).

The bad thing about it is, that it requires the version of Visual Studio that came with the SQL server version (so no designing of SSRS 2008 R1/R2 reports in Visual Studio 2010, you need Visual Studio 2008).

Answer (score 0):

take a look into [List & Label](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/.NET-Visual-Studio-WPF%20%22List%20&%20Label%22.). It has a Webserveredition for generating output on web-applications and if you need to modify them there is an ActiveX available. We've done some successful projects with this stuff. Just try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Izenda AdHoc](http://www.izenda.com/Site/Pages/ReportsForMvc.aspx) 
. 
In-browser Designer, In-browser Viewes, highly customizable but very simple API, exports feature, multiple databases types support.
You could even change reports looking using CSS styles.

Of course, compatible with MVC.